# WordPress, Woocommerce with Storefront. PHP Code displayed below the footer

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

I am not sure where to look for this. When in preview of the theme, or logged as admin, everything is fine. But when I am not logged, as an average user, there are a couple of lines of PHP code displayed below the footer:

```
var _paq = _paq || []; _paq.push(["setDocumentTitle", document.domain + "/" + document.title]); _paq.push(["setCookieDomain", "*.lebearcnc.com"]); _paq.push(["setDomains", ["*.lebearcnc.com"]]); _paq.push(['trackPageView']); _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']); (function() { var u="//stats.bgsoftfactory.net/"; _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']); _paq.push(['setSiteId', 6]); var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.defer=true
```

Looks like some javascript code has a syntax error. This stay the same even if I switch themes, so it is not theme dependant. Thanks if you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Sorry, did not take the time to check. Simply de-activated the plugin. I may search later, when I have some time, but I am in a hurry right now.

Answer (score 0):

Found the culprit! Deactivating piwik extension solved the problem.